# Intuition behind a result in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measured space and let $w : X \to [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function. Define
$$
\nu(A) := \int_A w \,\ d\mu \qquad (A \in \mathcal{A}).
$$
Then $\nu$ is a measure on $(X, \mathcal{A})$, and if $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then $f \in L^1(\nu) \Leftrightarrow fw \in L^1(\mu)$ and in that case we have
$$
\int_X f \,\ d\nu = \int_X (fw) \,\ d\mu.
$$
**My question is :** Is there an intuitive way to understand this result ? Why is this equality not so surprising ?

I was thinking that maybe we could interpret $w$ as a mass density and so $\nu$ would measure the mass of a given entity $A \in \mathcal{A}$... ?

Comment: Does change of variable in pre-analysis integration make sense? If so, then this is just a restatement of it.

Comment: Could you explain how this is a restatement of the change of variable ? Actually a similar result says that $\int_Y f \,\ d\nu = \int_X (f \circ \phi) \,\ d\mu$ where $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a measured space, $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ a measurable space and $\nu(B) := \mu(\phi^{-1}(B))$ ($B \in \mathcal{B}$). I don't quite understand intuitively this result neither, but it looks more like a change of variable formula to me than the one in the question ?

Answer (score 2):

As to "not so surprising" I'd say its because the equality trivially holds when $f$ is a simple function. But this doesn't go very far toward intuition. I think your mass density is spot on. A good example is when $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $w$ is a probability distribution. In this case the equality is saying something like integrating $f$ over the probability space is the same as integrated $f$ weighted point-wise by the distribution over all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. So would it be fair to say that the result tells us that "weighting $f$ by a weighted weight" is the same as "weighting $f$ two times" ?